# 起動中のSQLServerのバージョンを特定する方法

Tags: sql, windows-server

社内のサーバーを運用しております情シス担当のものです。
表題件について知見をお持ちの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただくたく。。

現在運用しておりますサーバー内に、SQLServerが3バージョン（2008,2012,2014）インストールされております。
とある事情から「現在利用していないSQLServerはアンインストールをしなさい」という指令が出ており、いろいろと確認していたのですが、どうも小職では特定できそうにありません・・・。

Windows上から起動中のバージョンを確認・特定する方法はあるのでしょうか？
それともサーバー内で稼働しているアプリ元へ問い合わせするしかないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

SQL サーバは重複起動していないと仮定して、手っ取り早くは SQL サーバに接続して以下のクエリの実行結果を確認する方法があるようです。

[SQL Server のバージョン確認方法](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql-serversql-server-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)

> 以下の SQL コマンドを実行すると、結果として SQL Serverの製品名、プロダクトバージョン、導入日時、エディション、OS のバージョンとエディションの情報が取得できます。
>
> ```
> SELECT @@VERSION
> ```
>
> (結果の例)
>
> ```
> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64) Oct 28 2016 18:17:30 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393:  ) (Hypervisor)
> ```